# ISO Pascal record variants without a field name

Tags: record, pascal, variant

I'm slightly confused trying to figure a section of ISO Pascal.

The grammar allows you to do this:

```
type RPoint = Record
  Case Boolean of
    False : (X,Y,Z : Real);
    True : (R,theta,phi : Real);
end;
```

To construct it, you do:

```
var p: RPoint;
begin
  p.x := 1;
end.
```

There's one part I don't understand: what's the purpose of the `Case Boolean` part? I understand that you can do `case MyVal: Boolean`; then `MyVal` becomes the field selector. However, what is the purpose when there is no field selector, just a type?

In addition, the standard says:

> With each variant-part shall be associated a type designated the selector-type possessed by the
>   variant-part . If the variant-selector of the variant-part contains a tag-field, or if the case-constant-
>   list of each variant of the variant-part contains only one case-constant, then the selector-type shall
>   be denoted by the tag-type, and each variant of the variant-part shall be associated with those
>   values specified by the selector-type denoted by the case-constants of the case-constant-list of the
>   variant . Otherwise, the selector-type possessed by the variant-part shall be a new ordinal-type that
>   is constructed to possess exactly one value for each variant of the variant-part, and no others, and
>   each such variant shall be associated with a distinct value of that type.

I don't quite understand what the `selector-type` is and why it would be a new `ordinal-type`. Wouldn't the `selector-type` just be the type like in `case Boolean of`? And what does each `case-constant-list` having only one `case-constant` have to do with it?

Comment: In the past the comp.lang.pascal.ansi-iso newsgroup was the best source for ISO details, and despite that it hasn't seen action in years there still might be lurkers. Other than that, try to search the Gnu Pascal (GPC) documentation on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your variant record has two possible 'personalities'.  Boolean is a type with two possible values.  So, it seemed like a logical choice.  But, it doesn't have to be Boolean.

You could have used some other ordinal type such as Integer or Byte to get the same effect.  For example:

```
type RPoint = Record
  Case Byte of
    0: (X,Y,Z : Real);
    1: (R,theta,phi : Real);
end;
```

Comment: So the type serves no actual runtime representation? It just is for defining the different "personalities"?

Comment: Exactly.  It's just a type for what will be used later for each case.  It's only  useful for the compiler.  There is no run-time storage for it.

Comment: One more question: what does the whole thing about having on `case-constant` mean? Or is it just useless "standard" crap?